Bash printf format for Eszett (scharfes S, sharp s) takes up 2 positions
I want to use printf under bash to format german verbs as follows:
INFINITIV       PRATERITUM      PERFEKT         3.PERS. SING
heißen          hieß            hat geheißen    er heißt
kaufen          kaufte          hat gekauft     er kauft

I use a simple printf commando in my bash script:
printf "%-15s %-15s %-15s %-15s %-15s\n" "INFINITIV" "PRATERITUM" "PERFEKT" "3.PERS. SING"
printf "%-15s %-15s %-15s %-15s %-15s\n" "heißen" "hieß" "hat geheißen" "er heißt"
printf "%-15s %-15s %-15s %-15s %-15s\n" "kaufen" "kaufte" "hat gekauft" "er kauft"

But is seems that the Eszett is seen as two characters. Therefore on the screen after every ß the text shifts one position to the left. The output is:
pwp@linuxcomputers:~/Scripts/Test$ Deutsche-Verben-Scharf-S 
INFINITIV       PRATERITUM      PERFEKT         3.PERS. SING                   
heißen         hieß           hat geheißen   er heißt                      
kaufen          kaufte          hat gekauft     er kauft

How can I prevent this shift and make the printf formatting do what it is intended to do?

POSIX requires printf's %-15s to count those 15 in terms of bytes. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/350240/why-is-printf-shrinking-umlaut and use e.g. ${#var}. Also note that your sample uses %-15s five times but you only provide four values per line.

See here for the very same issue and my solutions to it: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/592479/310674

You can write a wrapper for printf that takes this into account.

With a function to pad your strings at the end:
pad() {
  local string="$1              "
  echo "${string:0:15}"
}

printf "%s %s %s %s\n" "$(pad "INFINITIV")" "$(pad "PRATERITUM")" "$(pad "PERFEKT")" "$(pad "3.PERS. SING")"
printf "%s %s %s %s\n" "$(pad "heißen")" "$(pad "hieß")" "$(pad "hat geheißen")" "$(pad "er heißt")"
printf "%s %s %s %s\n" "$(pad "kaufen")" "$(pad "kaufte")" "$(pad "hat gekauft")" "$(pad "er kauft")"

Output:

INFINITIV       PRATERITUM      PERFEKT         3.PERS. SING   
heißen          hieß            hat geheißen    er heißt       
kaufen          kaufte          hat gekauft     er kauft

